# How to add margin inside a parbox?

Tags: parbox

I have create a parbox as below that I would like to have a margin between the border the text for top, bottom, left, and right:

```
\begin{center}\shadowbox{\parbox{0.85\textwidth}{text text text}}\end{center}
```

Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The distance to the frame is controlled by `\fboxsep`.  This can in fact be found in the documentation ([PDF](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancybox/fancybox-doc.pdf)):

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \setlength\fboxsep{1cm}
  \shadowbox{\parbox{0.85\textwidth}{text text text}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]